# Apply style to a (pandas) DataFrame index according to row criteria

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-styles

I'd like to apply styling to my the index of my df is some *per row* criteria is satisfied.

The code I have is

```
data = {"Labels": ["foo", "bar"], "Values":[1, -1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.set_index('Labels')
df
```

I'd like to have a yellow background  in the `Label` column if the value is positive. I tried

```
df.style.apply(lambda x:  ['background-color: yellow' if x[1]>0 else '', ''])
```

but no luck. What is that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x` in your lambda function is a `pd.Series`.

`x[1]` is just the second value of that series. In your example, just `-1`. Since `-1 > 0`, nothing happens.

You probably want to check that for every value of `x`, [as given as example in the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html#Building-Styles)

```
df.style.apply(lambda x:['background-color: yellow' if s>0 else '' for s in x])
```

Also [per docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html), in **Limitations** section,

> You can **only style the values**, not the index or columns

Comment: I tried this, but this will color the cell that contains `1` while I want to color `foo`

Comment: As per new answer this is now out of date and index styling is available from pandas 1.4.0

Answer (score 1):

As of pandas 1.4.0, you can now apply styling to the index with `apply_index()`

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply_index.html

Unfortunately, I don't know offhand how to apply this styling based on a cell value. It should be possible, though.

I know this is only a partial solution, but this result came up when I searched on how to apply styling to the index, and it's important to know that `apply_index()` is now available. Hope this helps someone.